# Dog doesn't walk away from incoming car in driveway

Tags: dogs, behavior, training

One of my dogs doesn't stand up and walk away from my car as I am parking it in the garage. Not even when I honk, she just looks at the car a bit annoyed and goes back to sleep, or chewing something. It makes it really hard to park or leave the house. Is there anyway to teach her to move away without making her scared of vehicles?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution that comes to my mind is squirting water at her. It's a method often used by professional dog trainers to discourage unwanted behavior without punishing the dog or causing her pain.

Usually people use a small water bottle with a [sports cap](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sports_cap_(bottle)_-_open.jpg) that allows them to squirt the water a meter or so away. If you don't want to leave your car, you may have to resort to some type of powerful water squirting gun that can reach the dog even further away. Just have the loaded water gun in your car (packed in a plastic bag to avoid leaks), lower the window and squirt water at your dog.

Throwing a small water balloon in her direction might be more efficient, but also more risky for your car. You shouldn't hit your dog directly with the balloon, just throw it at the ground directly in front of her to pop it.

The idea behind these methods is to disrupt your dog in what she's doing without causing her pain. Many dogs don't like getting wet, so they stand up and shake the water out of their fur. If your dog gets wet every time the car turns into the driveway, she'll stand up and move away before getting wet eventually. Unfortunately some dogs don't mind getting wet and this method doesn't work on them.

The only alternative I know in that case is to fill a few small screws, washers or nuts into an empty small plastic bottle and throwing the bottle in her direction. The rattling sound it makes when hitting the ground should be enough to make her move. You must make sure to never throw the bottle directly at her because you can actually injure her (nose, eyes, ears, paws and more) with a direct hit from the cap or the rigid edge around the cap.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it.